# How can I Host my files present in resources through Spring Boot App

Tags: java, file, spring-boot, filesystems, hosting

I have a requirement in which I have to store some files within the Spring Boot Application and on API hit I should provide a URL for each file present within the Spring Application.

Any advice on how can I achieve it, without any Storage Service like S3.
Java Files and the hosting files should be within the same project and same server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked Spring Boot [Static Content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) section?

Comment: @Boris let me check on it